# Cleaning alpha hull image

Tags: r, geospatial

This is the result of applying `ahull` function from the R package `alphahull` to my 2D set of points. How do I remove those thick black dots from my image? Thanks!

[image: Alphahull]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply hiding points of your data seems questionable, but this solution does what you describe by getting the coordinates of the points outside the hull from the `ahull` object and overlays the points with invisible ones. With this you do not have to change the input data or the `ahull` object.

```
library(alphahull)

lim=5
mat <- matrix(data=rnorm(1000), ncol=2)

some_hull = ahull(mat, alpha=0.5)
plot(some_hull, xlim = c(-lim,lim), ylim = c(-lim,lim))
```

[image]

The arc object `ahull$arcs` contains an indicator in the third column which points are outside of the hull. You can use these coordinates and simply overlay slightly bigger invisible points to hide the original ones, without having to change the input data or the object.

```
non_members <- some_hull$arcs[which(some_hull$arcs[, 3] == 0), 1:2]

plot(some_hull, xlim = c(-lim,lim), ylim = c(-lim,lim))
points(non_members, col="white", pch=19, cex=1.2)
```

[image]